# Internal error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'psa.domainaliases' doesn't exist

Tags: plesk

How do I resolve this error-

```
Internal error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'psa.domainaliases' doesn't exist
```

I tried upgrading from Plesk 9 to 11.0.9 and when I click on Domains, I get this error.

Please let me know.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Solved myself.

The error says table not found, but when I checked the database, the table was there. Problem was with the permission of below files. From 644, I changed it to 755 as-

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4947 Feb  2 20:15 /usr/share/psa-horde/lib/Horde/Rdo/Adapter/Pdo.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14384 Feb  2 20:15 /opt/psa/admin/plib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
```

I am not sure if permission of both the files needs to be changed or any single one, but for now after changing permission of both the files, this issue has been re-solved.